# How to have an 'if' within a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to solve a problem whereas, but I feel the loop I've got has a missing link somewhere...

The brief I've been given -
"Now write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months."

In essence what I've done is far, is code up something that will take a base value (10 for example), take it away from the credit card balance (taking into account the interest), and if the total number of months it takes to put the balance into a negative (e.g. paid off) is above 12, it adds to the 'minmonth' (amount to be paid off per month) until the number of months is equal to is or below 12.

Apologies in advance, I've literally only been learning Python for 2 days!

Where am I going wrong?

```
balance = float(raw_input('Enter the outstanding balance on your creditcard: '))
interest = float(raw_input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:     '))

minmonth = 10
months = 0
monthlyinterest =  interest / 12

while(balance > 0):
    balance = balance * (1 + monthlyinterest) - minmonth
    months = months + 1

    if(months > 12):
        months = 0
        minmonth = minmonth + 10

else:
    print 'RESULT!'
    print 'Total amount to pay per month would be'
    print minmonth
    print 'Total amounts to pay'
    print months
```

Comment: When you compile your code it will throw an `IndentationError` so something is wrong with indentation as python heavily depends on it.

Comment: @RanRag:  Not true.  You can have branch conditions after looping statements, although it's more common to see them after `for` loops.

Answer (score 5):

Indentation is important in Python.  You would want to bring the `else` in line with the `if` statement in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Your "else" is not lining up with your "if". Python needs perfect indentation to recognize loop and statement's scope.

Edit to add Tim's comment below, which I didn't point out clearly:
"Its worth adding it needs that indentation because it uses it in place of explicit begin/end statements or braces {} that would serve the purpose of grouping code together in other languages."

Comment: True, but its worth adding it needs that indentation because it uses it in place of explicit begin/end statements or braces {} that would serve the purpose of grouping code together in other languages.